# splitting a formula and again regenerating and reevaluateing formula

Tags: regex, split, tcl

I m splitting a formula string  with `"*/+-()"` as my pattern (for eg. `a*b+c` is string) and I m getting a list in the output as `(a b c)` where `a`,`b`,`c` are variables and contain some values like `5`,`10`,`15`.

What I need is: I should be able to directly substitute values in the variables and evaluate the expression.

The formula is  taken from the user and changes time to time. so if the user enters `(a/b)`, something should automatically replace it with real values `(5/10)` and then return the result 0.5.

The formula is formed from limited number of variables (for eg. `a`,`b`,`c`) and it can use `+`,`-`,`*`,`/`,`(`,`)` as operators.

The problem is that after splitting the variables, i m not able to replace them with  their values or evaluate the equation. Please help me to do this task  in as short expression as possible. thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you simply pass the string to `expr`? It will make the necessary substitutions and return the result of the operation.

Comment: the input is like a*b+c. i need to convert a list of (a b c) to something like ($a*$b+$c). that's why it is complicated.

Comment: What if you have an array? As in `a(b)+c`? How would you differentiate it against `a(b*d)+c`? The first usually can become `$a(b)+$c` or `$a($b)+$c` while the second can be `$a($b*$d)+$c` or `$a($b*d)+$c` or  `$a(b*$d)+$c` or `$a(${b*d})+$c` or `$a(b*d)+$c`...?

Comment: there can be no arrays in input. the variables are scalars (in terms of perl...) but the real problem is to generate ($a*$b+$c) from (a b c).  @Jerry

Comment: Here is what I understand. You have a function (lets say `proc1`) which takes user input formula. You extract the variable names from that formula and pass these variables to a different function(lets say `proc2`) to substitute values for these variables. After `proc2` sets variable values, you are not able to evaluate the result of the original formula. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all that complicated:

First, replace all variables with with a Tcl variable (prepped a `$`).
You have to be careful not replace `sin(a)` with `$sin($a)` or similar.

```
regsub -all -inline {[a-z]+(?![a-z\(])} $input
```

Example:

```
set input {a*b+c+sin(d)}
regsub -all -inline {[a-z]+(?![a-z\(])} $input
```

would yield `$a+$b*$c+sin($c)`, which can be passed to `expr`.
If you need the variable names, just use regexp with this expression.

Comment: the problem is that the loop in which this substitution is to be done, we don't have the equation a*b+c. we have only (a b c). bcz the splitting happens way before entering the loop. so the loop only knows the list (a b c). the operators have to be fetched somewhere from outside. @Johannes

Comment: Wait, how should I know if `a b c` should mean `a*b+c` or `a-b/c`? (Or: where are the operators?)

Answer (score 0):

If you *know* the names of the variables and *none* of them are prefixes of anything else you use, you can easily transform the expression like this:

```
set a 1; set b 2; set c 3
set e "a*b+c"
set value [expr [string map {a $a b $b c $c} $e]]
puts "$e = $value"
```

Note: ***no braces*** around the expression on the third line. This is when you want to avoid safety like that because you are doing runtime generation of the expression.

That mapping can be generated automatically:

```
set a 1; set b 2; set c 3
set e "a*b+c"
set vars {a b c}
set value [expr [string map [regsub -all {\w+} "& $&"] $e]]
puts "$e = $value"
```

However, if you've got prefixes and other things like that, you need a more complex transform:

```
# Omitting the variable setup and print at the end...
proc replIfRight {vars word} {
    if {$word in $vars} {return \$$word} else {return $word}
}
set value [expr [subst [regsub -all {\w+} [string map {[ \[ $ \$ \\ \\\\} $e] {[replIfRight $vars &]}]]]
```

You're absolutely right to not expect to come up with such a horrible thing yourself!